# ColdFusion 11 REST returning 404

Tags: apache, rest, coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I cannot seem to get CF REST to work at all.
After trying the docs and a couple articles verbatim, I get a 404.

I am using apache - and according to other posts,
JkMountFile "C:/ColdFusion11/config/wsconfig/1/uriworkermap.properties"
May be needed - I added it just in case, but that doesn't seem to make a difference.

APACHE VHOST

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName   127.0.0.1
    ServerAlias  127.0.0.1
    DocumentRoot "C:/wwwroot/CFREST2"
    ErrorLog     "C:/wwwroot/CFREST2/logs/error.log"
    CustomLog    "C:/wwwroot/CFREST2/logs/access.log" combined
    JkMountFile "C:/ColdFusion11/config/wsconfig/1/uriworkermap.properties"
    <Directory   "C:/wwwroot/CFREST2/logs/">
        AllowOverride None
        Options None
        Order allow,deny
        Deny from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Example:

```
CFADMIN - registered 
Root path: C:\wwwroot\CFREST2
Host: 127.0.0.1
Service Mapping: test
```

FILE: (C:\wwwroot\CFREST2\rest3.cfc)

```
<cfcomponent rest="true" restpath="restService" >

    <cffunction name="sayHello" access="remote" returntype="String" httpmethod="GET" >

        <cfset rest = "Hello World" >

    <cfreturn rest >

</cffunction>
```

MAKING GET REQUEST IN POSTMAN:

```
http://127.0.0.1/rest/test/restService/
```

RETURNS:

```
404
```

MAKING GET REQUEST IN POSTMAN:

```
http://127.0.0.1/rest/test/restService/sayHello
```

RETURNS:

```
404
```

I have tried a few variations, abut ALWAYS get the 404.

Comment: The Host in CF Admin REST Services is optional - are you sure it should be set to 127.0.0.1? Are you testing it on your local machine? Try leaving it empty maybe. 

Try changing restpath="restService"  to restpath="/restService" 

Also - in CF Admin - Data & Services > REST Services - click on the refresh button and check if it refreshed correctly - there should be a "Server has been updated successfully" message at the top. 

GET http://127.0.0.1/rest/test/restService should be the correct path.

Comment: Well, one of my test folders started working after I came back from lunch...While one is still throwing the 404s

I suspect a service reboot did the trick - but Im still confused as to why - restarting the service is not mentioned in any docs. 

It's far too inconsistent and the "rest" addition to the path resolution along with some other weirdness will prevent me from using CF for my REST APIs. I think CF missed this boat.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, over 4 years after the question was asked, and I haven't used CF for a while, and I'm trying to work my way through setting up a RESTful service.

I was getting a 404, and saw this in my exception.log:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: .../cfusion/wwwroot/WEB-INF/rest-skeletons/path.to.component.Fubar.class (Permission denied)

I checked and the account running the service didn't have permission to write to the "rest-skeletons" directory.  I changed that, no more 404, on to the next problem!

Answer (score 0):

Try to initialize by running this in the separate .cfm file:

```
<cfset restInitApplication("C:\wwwroot\CFREST2","test")>
```

To call:
http://127.0.0.1/rest/test/restService